# How to use a variable in a different function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to print out the latitude (lat) variable in the javascript below.

How do I refer to the lat variable? `this.lat, that.lat, vicinity.lat` etc ?

In my javascript I have

```
var Vicinity = function (pubReference, sessionId, done, err) {
    this.ad = {
        getBannerHtml: function () {
            console.log(this.lat); // how do I refer to the lat variable?
        }
    };

    this.init = function (done, err) {
        var that = this;
        this.getLatLng(that, function (position) {
            that.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        }, err);
        if (typeof done === 'function')
            done(this);
    };

    this.init(done, err);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = new Vicinity(pubReference, sessionId,
        function (result) {
            $("#sticky").html(result.ad.getBannerHtml());
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: If you don't "own" the iFrame, i.e. it's on the same domain as the parent page, you cannot access variables from within it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142285/access-iframe-content-from-parent-jquery

Comment: You are mistaken, if you think that `this` in `getBannerHtml` refer to `Vicinity` or to created instance by `Vicinity`, it's refer to `this.ad` object. So, would be better if you cache this into variable  `that`. Look at [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/U5xZ4/)

Comment: In the function getBannerHtml: function() how do I refer to the lat and lon variables? this.lat, that.lat, vicinity.ad.lat ?

Comment: in this case `console.log(this.lat);` _this_ is `Vicinity.ad`

Comment: Nitpick: In this code, `lat` is a property, not a variable.

Comment: you can use `that.ad.lat = position.coords.latitude;` instead of `that.lat = position.coords.latitude;`

Comment: Does `Vicinity` contain lat anywhere? What is the object structure? Maybe you can `console.log(this)` to see where actually `lat` is...

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there. You already are declaring `that` to be `this` in `init()`. Just do that throughout the function and it should work:

```
var Vicinity = function (pubReference, sessionId, done, err) {
    var that = this;
    this.ad = {
        getBannerHtml: function () {
            console.log(that.lat); // how do I refer to the lat variable?
        }
    };

    this.init = function (done, err) {
        var that = this;
        this.getLatLng(that, function (position) {
            that.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        }, err);
        if (typeof done === 'function')
            done(this);
    };

    this.init(done, err);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = new Vicinity(pubReference, sessionId,
        function (result) {
            $("#sticky").html(result.ad.getBannerHtml());
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also call the getBannerHtml method in the scope of your Vicinity by using the "apply" function. The "this" variable is set to the object you pass.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = new Vicinity(pubReference, sessionId,
        function (result) {
            $("#sticky").html(result.ad.getBannerHtml.apply(result));
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I already posted in another post but got another idea ;)
It is kind of obvious but works.

```
getBannerHtml: function(lat, lon) {
  return '<iframe src="http://foo.com?pr=34&lat'+ lat +'=&lon=' + lon + '"></iframe>';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var pubReference = 1;
  var sessionId = "1";
  var data = new Vicinity (pubReference, sessionId, 
    function(result) {
      $("#sticky").html(result.ad.getBannerHtml(result.lat, result.lon));
    }
  );
});
```

You can also call the getBannerHtml method in the scope of your Vicinity by using the "apply" function. The "this" variable is set to the object you pass.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var pubReference = 1;
    var sessionId = "1";
    var data = new Vicinity(pubReference, sessionId,
        function (result) {
            $("#sticky").html(result.ad.getBannerHtml.apply(result));
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: FYI: moved from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594306/how-to-pass-values-to-a-function